# Modal disappears due to mouseup event (highlight input field in modal and release mouse outside modal)

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, modal-dialog

An interesting bug where you have a modal with form input fields in it. You then highlight the text in one of the input fields, so the [mousedown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) event occurs inside the modal, but the [mouseup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseup) event occurs outside the modal.

Chrome 73 interprets the mouseup event outside the modal as a click, and closes the modal.

Here's the original modal code:

```
<div class="modal-wrapper" (click)="close()">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
    <div class="modal-container" (click)="stopEvent($event)">
        <!-- modal content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to change the click event that closes the modal to a mousedown event instead:

```
<div class="modal-wrapper" (mousedown)="close()">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
    <div class="modal-container" (mousedown)="stopEvent($event)">
        <!-- modal content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```